# How to get rid of magic strings by using VisualStateManager.GoToState

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visualstatemanager

This Problem appears while using the `VisualStateManager`of WPF:
At first the state is created:

```
<VisualState Name="MagicString">
    #Storyboard etc.
</VisualState>
```

And then the set of the state is called like this:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(element, "MagicString", true);
```

The Question now is, how to get rid of this magic string of the state name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2009/12/29/no-more-magic-strings-with-visualstatemanager-gotostate.aspx).
The problem can be solved by changing `Name` to `x:Name` like this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="MagicString">
    #Storyboard etc.
</VisualState>
```

will create a field in the view class which can be acessed by codebehind. So the call works like this:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(element, MagicString.Name, true);
```